# Mongoose Get Last Item Of Array From Field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is my schema;

```
...
  edge: {
    name: [
      {
        type: String
      }
    ],
    image: [
      {
        type: String
      }
    ]
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
...
```

I want to select last `edge.name` and `edge.image` field. For example;

```
MySchema.find({user: req.user._id},{_id:0, edge:1})
```

But edge come 4 name. I want to just last one, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$slice](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/) with a negative number `n` as projection to get the last `n` elements of array. In your case it should be:

```
MySchema.find(
  {user: req.user._id},
  {
    "edge.name": {
      "$slice": -1
    },
    "edge.image": {
      "$slice": -1
    }
  }
)
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ctKknNSqwNS)